# ModelChoiceField always raises : “Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices”

Tags: python, django, ajax

In forms I have multiple dependent choice fields. but I am getting same error for all the dependent choice fields i tried but it wont come please help me.I am fresher.

forms.py

```
class IssuecreateForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs,):
        self.projects = kwargs.pop("projects",None) 
        # self.issues = kwargs.pop("issues",None) 
        # self.rootcause = kwargs.pop("rootcause",None) 
        super(IssuecreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['SUMMARY'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control','placeholder': 'Enter Summary'})
        self.fields['SUMMARY'].label='Summary'
        self.fields['DESCRIPTION'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control mb-4','placeholder': 'Enter Description'},required=False)
        self.fields['DESCRIPTION'].label='Description'
        self.fields['ENVIRONMENT'].widget.attrs.update({'class' : 'form-control mb-4','placeholder': 'Enter Description'},required=False)
        self.fields['ENVIRONMENT'].label='Environment'
        self.fields['PROJECT'].queryset = self.projects
        self.fields['LINKED_ISSUES'].choices = [(x.ID, x.SUMMARY) for x in Issues.objects.all()]
    LABELS =forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select({'class': 'lable-select', 'name':"lable-select", "multiple":"multiple"}), choices=OPTIONS,required=False)
    CREATED_DATE_TIME=forms.DateTimeField(initial=datetime.datetime.today(),required=False)
    PROJECT = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all(),widget=CustomSelectOption(attrs={'class':'mt-2'}))
    PRIORITY = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Priority.objects.none(),widget=CustomSelectOption(attrs={'class':'mt-2','name':'issue-types'}))
    TYPE = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=IssueType.objects.none(),widget=CustomSelectOption(attrs={'class':'mt-2'}))
    LINKED_ISSUE_TYPES = ModelChoiceField(queryset=LinkedIssueType.objects.none(), empty_label='----------Select Linked Issue Type---------')
    # STATUS = ModelChoiceField(queryset=IssueStatus.objects.none(), empty_label='----------Select Status---------')
    RESOLUTIONS = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Resolution.objects.none(),required=False, empty_label='----------Select Resolution---------')
    ROOT_CAUSES = ModelChoiceField(queryset=RootCause.objects.none(),required=False, empty_label='----------Select Rootcause---------')
    PROCESS_AREAS = ModelChoiceField(queryset=ProcessArea.objects.none(),required=False, empty_label='----------Select Process Area---------')
    FUNCTIONAL_AREAS = ModelChoiceField(queryset=FunctionalArea.objects.none(),required=False, empty_label='----------Select Functional Area---------')
    # DEFECT_TYPE = ModelChoiceField(queryset=DefectType.objects.none(), empty_label='----------Select Defect Type---------')
    ASSIGNEE = MyModelChoiceField(queryset= PmUser.objects.none(),widget=CustomSelectOption(attrs={'class':'mt-2'}),required=False)
    REPORTER = MyModelChoiceField(queryset= PmUser.objects.none(),widget=CustomSelectOption(attrs={'class':'mt-2'}),required=False)
    SPRINTS = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Sprint.objects.none(),required=False, empty_label='----------Select Sprint---------')
    LINKED_ISSUES = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select({"class":"issue-list", "name":"issue-list", "multiple":"multiple"}),choices = [],required=False)
    # EPIC_LINK = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select({"class":"issue-list", "name":"issue-list"}),choices = [])
    DURATION_CHOICES=forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'placeholder': 'METHOD_TYPE','class':'myclass'}),required=False,choices=DURATION_CHOICES) 
    class Meta:
        model = Issues
        fields ='__all__'
        exclude=['CREATOR','UPDATOR','CREATED_DATE_TIME','UPDATED_DATE_TIME','EPIC_LINK','WATCHER','PARENT','LINKED_ISSUES','ORDER','SERIAL_NUMBER','COLOR','DEFECT_TYPE','STATUS','EPIC_NAME']
        widgets = {
            'START_DATE': DateInput(),
            'DUE_DATE': DateInput(),
            'ESTIMATION_TIME': DurationInput(),
            }
```

Comment: for which field do you get this error? show us the actual error.

Comment: if you set the queryset to `none()` then no choice will ever be valid...